# identityserver4 Quickstart LoginViewModel IsExternalLogInOnly flag

Tags: identityserver4

I am using Identityserver with multiple external authorities(providers). The scenario which I am trying to get here is I have a client configured with "EnableLocalLogin" as false. I do have multiple external providers. The below code line in the "LoginViewModel.cs" in the quick start is not making sense.

public bool IsExternalLoginOnly => EnableLocalLogin == false && ExternalProviders?.Count() == 1;

This is returning false and I am not getting redirected to external provider. Should this be ExternalProviders?.Count() > 0

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, `IsExternalLoginOnly` is not well named. it is called only when you show the login page :

```cs
[HttpGet]        
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(string returnUrl)  
{           
    var vm = await _account.BuildLoginViewModelAsync(returnUrl);            
    if (vm.IsExternalLoginOnly)            
    {                   
        // only one option for logging in                
        return await ExternalLogin(vm.ExternalProviders.First().AuthenticationScheme, returnUrl); 
    }           
    return View(vm);        
}
```

It is used to directly redirect to a provider in case the user has no choice about it.

Now in your case, you have multiple external providers and you have to ask the user which one to use. You can not automaticly pass this step as long as your client allows multiple providers

You can still code your own login and try to automate this step following the `returnUrl`